# Rindler motion constant acceleration proper time

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

I have problem to calculate the proper time for [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates):
the coordinates in Minkowski space with constant acceleration are given by:$$
\begin{alignat}{7}
t' &~=~ \frac{c}{g}   \, && \sinh{\left(\frac{g}{c\tau}\right)} \\
x' &~=~ \frac{c^2}{g} \, && \cosh{\left(\frac{g}{c\tau}\right)}
\end{alignat}
$$

The proper time is
$$
\tau_{\text{p}}~=~\int{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2 \left(t' \right)}{c^2}}}\, \mathrm{d}t'
\,,$$with$$
\begin{alignat}{7}
t'           & ~=~ \frac{c}{g} \, && \sinh{\left(\frac{g}{c\tau}\right)} \\
\mathrm{d}t' & ~=~                && \cosh{\left(\frac{g}{c\tau}\right)} \,.
\end{alignat}
$$

How can I calculate $v \left(t' \right)$?

Comment: $v(t')=dx'/dt'$ ?

Comment: Also, I think you could use the fact that $\tau=t'/\gamma$.

Comment: $  dx'/dt'=c$
so $\tau_p=0$ ????

Comment: so

$v(\tau)=dx'/dt'=c\tanh(g/c \,\tau)$

and

$\tau_p=\int\sqrt(1-(v^2(\tau))/c^2)\,\cosh(g/c\,\tau)\,d\tau$

I think this is o.k.
Tank you

Comment: (1) Physically, $v(t)$ should tend towards $c$ as $\tau\rightarrow\infty$, so getting $v=c\tanh(.)$ seems right. (2) I think your LaTeX messed up.

Comment: Oh and also I messed up, it should be $d\tau=dt'/\gamma$, i.e. only differentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity is defined as $dx'/dt'$, which in your case comes out to be:

$$v'=\frac{dx'}{dt'}=c\tanh\left(\frac{g\tau}{c}\right)$$

where $g$ is the proper acceleration. Notice that as $\tau\rightarrow\infty$, $v\rightarrow c$, as we would expect.

From this, you can calculate the proper time itself $d\tau=dt'/\gamma$.

$$\begin{align}
d\tau&=dt'\sqrt{1-v'^2/c^2}\\
&=\left(d\tau\cosh\left(\frac{g\tau}{c}\right)\right)\sqrt{1-\tanh^2\left(\frac{g\tau}{c}\right)}\\
&=d\tau
\end{align}$$

as expected. If you want to find $\tau$ as a function of $t'$, you would integrate:

$$\begin{align}
\tau&=\int_{t'_0}^{t'} dt''\sqrt{1-v'(t'')^2/c^2}\\
&=\int_{t'_0}^{t'} dt''\left(1+\sinh^2(g\tau(t'')/c)\right)^{-1/2}\\
&=\int_{t'_0}^{t'} dt''\left(1+(gt''/c)^2\right)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac{c}{g}\left[\sinh^{-1}(gt'/c)-\sinh^{-1}(gt'_0/c)\right]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Tank you.
I have this Problem:
You go on the Rindler geodesic for 10 [s] with g=10 [m/s^2] and the next 
20 [s] with g=5 [m/s^2] . How many meter you travel on the geodesic

Comment: @Eli Split the problem in two parts: first, 10 seconds of g=10 m/s^2 acceleration starting from rest; second, 20 seconds of g=5 m/s^2 acceleration starting from the position and velocity from which you left the previous (first) motion.